# ts2339) Property phone does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

React-Router receive code

```
 import React from "react";
 import { Mutation } from "react-apollo";
 import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";
 import { toast } from "react-toastify";
 import { LOG_USER_IN } from "../../sharedQueries.local";
 import { verifyPhone, verifyPhoneVariables } from "../../types/api";
 import VerifyPhonePresenter from "./VerifyPhonePresenter";
 import { VERIFY_PHONE } from "./VerifyPhoneQueries";

interface IState {
  verificationKey: string;
  phoneNumber:string; 
}

interface IProps extends RouteComponentProps<any> {}

class VerifyMutation extends Mutation<verifyPhone, 
verifyPhoneVariables> {}

class VerifyPhoneContainer extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
 constructor(props: IProps) {
   super(props);
   if (!props.location.state) {
     props.history.push("/");
   }
   debugger;
   this.state = {
     phoneNumber: props.location.state.phone,
     verificationKey: ""
   };
 }
```

React-Router send code

```
import React from "react";
import { Mutation, MutationFn } from "react-apollo";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import {
  startPhoneVerification,
  startPhoneVerificationVariables
} from "../../types/api";
import PhoneLoginPresenter from "./PhoneLoginPresenter";
import { PHONE_SIGN_IN } from "./PhoneQueries";

interface IState {
  countryCode: string;
  phoneNumber: string;
}

class PhoneSignInMutation extends Mutation<
   startPhoneVerification,
   startPhoneVerificationVariables
 > {}

class PhoneLoginContainer extends React.Component<
   RouteComponentProps<any>,
   IState
> {
   public phoneMutation: MutationFn;
   public state = {
      countryCode: "+82",
      phoneNumber: ""
  };

  public render() {
    const { history } = this.props;
    const { countryCode, phoneNumber } = this.state;
    return (
     <PhoneSignInMutation
       mutation={PHONE_SIGN_IN}
       variables={{
         phoneNumber: `${countryCode}${phoneNumber}`
       }}
       onCompleted={data => {
         const { StartPhoneVerification } = data;
         const phone = `${countryCode}${phoneNumber}`;
         if (StartPhoneVerification.ok) {
           toast.success("SMS Sent! Redirecting you...");
           setTimeout(() => {
             history.push({
               pathname: "/verify-phone",
               state: {
                 phone
               }
             });
           }, 2000);
         } else {
        toast.error(StartPhoneVerification.error);
      }
    }}
  >
    {(phoneMutation, { loading }) => {
      this.phoneMutation = phoneMutation;
      return (
        <PhoneLoginPresenter
          countryCode={countryCode}
          phoneNumber={phoneNumber}
          onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
          onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
          loading={loading}
        />
      );
    }}
  </PhoneSignInMutation>
);
```

}

Failed to compile. Property 'phone' does not exist on type '{}'.

Please let me know why the error is occurring.

I'm going to make a text message and authentication with my cell phone.

However, the error below occurs while handing over the phone number to the next page from the previous page.

I am using a translator because my English is not good.

Comment: Could you please clarify the object structure and the response you're getting?

Comment: I added "interface" to "React-Router response".  

   nterface IState {
     verificationKey: string;
     phoneNumber:string; 
   }

Comment: Care to show the response object?

Comment: i solved 
 if (!props.location.state) {
      props.history.push("/");
    }
    const {
      location: { state }
    } = props;
    let phoneNumber = "";
    if (state) {
      phoneNumber = state.phone;
    } else {
      phoneNumber = "";
    }
    this.state = {
      phoneNumber,
      verificationKey: ""
    };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved

```
if (!props.location.state) {
         props.history.push("/");
       }
    const {
      location: { state }
    } = props;
    let phoneNumber = "";
    if (state) {
      phoneNumber = state.phone;
    } else {
      phoneNumber = "";
    }
    this.state = {
      phoneNumber,
      verificationKey: ""
    };
```